# Practical internet browser for working with tons of tabs?

Tags: windows, web-browser

I Am looking for an internet browser, which has following features without installing abhorrent addons!!! And addons are security risk, you shouldn't be forced to use them period...

- Reorder its windows on the taskbar and rename its titles (it has to
  be persistent even after restart!)
- intelligent session & tab manager
- text highlighter
- fully customizable hotkeys
- search when adding new bookmarks, so you can search for existing folders

I am using Windows 10 Pro x64. Price range 50-100$. Should also probably add, if it will cost that much it should be fast at least close to Firefox and reasonably secure; privacy don't care that much.

I cite this study, as browsers UI didn't really change since IE6. And it is terrible and causes pain: https://bigthink.com/technology-innovation/tab-overload

Comment: If such a thing exists, what OS should it run on – and how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions? Speaking of which, tracking/telemetry acceptable (as most browsers have that today) – or ad blocking required (so pages can be read without much fuss)?

Comment: On Windows 10. Probably like 50-100$ at this point. Since I can't do anything. I have easily over 1000 tabs when I work...

Comment: Tabs are for keeping loaded web pages "alive" in memory and thus each tab requires RAM. How much RAM does your system has to keep 1k tabs open? Otherwise use the bookmark feature to keep that much pages organized and open them if needed. Some web browser can open multiple pages at one by one bookmark.

Comment: I have 16GB ram, also 16GB page file, so this shouldn't be a problem. I had even 3000 tabs in Chrome once :D

Answer (score 0):

Vivaldi satisfies

- Intelligent Tab Manager
- Fully customizable hotkeys (including single key shortcuts)

You can search for bookmarks using the bookmarks panel but the search isn't that user friendly.

I don't know what you mean by a text highlighter.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Vivaldi doesn't come even close to this, I already asked there :(

Comment: all software devs are stupid, information age, tab overload and information overload is thing, yet there are studies... and browsers ui didn't change since 1999, i collabored on tab addon - Skeema, and devs told me i was brilliant after i gave them only most logical core things to improve... i don't understand why there is on market 100 to do apps totally same and have missing same core features and have same features and suffer from same issues, if you feel offended no one under 160IQ even understands me. i see everything everywhere is so inefficient it is crazy...

Comment: @empleat It's not like everybody uses the browser the same way. There are people that search for something online and then open the first link in the same page. And there are people that Ctrl+Click on every single link.

Comment: that's even more reason for my points, it is not customizable, you cannot even move windows, besides there were studies on this, software devs are so moronic i can give them basic core features and tips and they say i am brilliant or like most obvious logical things

Comment: @empleat I think you mean UX designers are moronic.
It feels like you want somebody to design a software specifically for you because you don't want to adjust to the features of existing software.